# шина данных и pub/sub

Tags: java, c#, архитектура, rabbitmq, zeromq

здравствуйте, пытаюсь понять что такое шина данных/шина сообщений(message bus) в распределенных системах... правильно ли понимаю, что:

1) при pub/sub модели, есть некий сервер, который принимает данные от производителя(producer), и отправляет их всем заинтересованным потребителям(consumer)... вот этот сервер и есть шина данных?

2) шина данных отправляет ВСЕ сообщения от каждого из производителей ВСЕМ потребителям... и только на основе, например, какого-то id, только определенный потребитель обрабатывает сообщение?

Comment: Скорее первое, потому что эффективнее. Но сервер это не сама шина, а ее контроллер или менеджер.

Answer (score 1):

Шина данных в физическом смысле - это одиночный сервер или кластер серверов, которые обслуживают передачу сообщений от отправителей к получателям.

Шина данных в логическом смысле - это сущность, через которую вы производите общение между вашими микросервисами. Для лёгкости масштабирования, микросервисы создаются бессостоятельными (не используют сессию пользователя и прочие механизмы) и являют собой ограниченный кусок логики, который может выполняться независимо от контекста всего приложения - они сами являются замкнутым контекстом. Шина сообщений - это сущность, через которую происходит логическое общение между этими замкнутыми контекстами.

Шина данных не обязательно отправляет ВСЕ сообщения от каждого из производителей ВСЕМ потребителям, вы можете гибко настраивать пересылку.

Например, вы создали объект Человек, который имеет метод СходитьВМагазин - для его реализации вам не нужен контекст микросервиса СетьКинотеатров, однако необходимо что-то понимать о сервисе РозничнаяТорговля, поэтому через шину сообщений вы можете послать событие "человек Иван Иванов пошёл в магазин №5 за булкой", а в сервисе РозничнаяТорговля принять это сообщение и вычесть 1 булку со склада этого магазина и отправить обратно в шину сообщение микросервису Люди о том, что у Ивана теперь есть булка. Этим самым вы, с помощью шины сообщений, изменили состояние в двух микросервисах для конкретных контекстов - Человека Ивана Иванова и РозничнойТорговли страны Россия. При этом, сервис СетьКинотеатров вообще не подписан на получение этого события из шины и ничего не знает о походе человека в Магазин - ему интересны только события о походах людей в кино.

Таким образом, создание конкретных контекстов на лету и применение шаблона "Единица Работы" вместе с шиной сообщений позволяют обходиться без сессии в микросервисах и тратить их ресурсы только в тех местах, где что-то действительно происходит и этих ресурсов требует.

Answer (score 0):

Именно первое. Кто-то что-то публикует, обработчик пересылает все подписчикам. Тем самым можно убрать любой модуль и ничего не сломается.